# How to use ace plugin in ionic application?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ace-plugin

I have added the ace plugin ionic (ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-ace). But i tried to access the

```
if (ace.platform == "Android")
```

but its gives me following error:

error:ReferenceError: ace is not defined

when i tried to use:

```
  if (window.ace.platform == "Android")
```

I am getting this error:

platform is not defined to undefined ace.

please help me how to use ACE plugin in my application?

Comment: Have you included cordova.js file in your HTML file? Also are you invoking plugin code inside platform ready function?

Comment: Yes I included the cordova.js in index.html but I am not invoking the code inside platform ready..I am invoking in my controller

Comment: I m not familiar with Ionic. But in vanilla cordova app, we use to invoke the plugin code inside deviceready event listener and i have heard ionic platform ready is the equivalent of cordova deviceready event. Please check on this

Comment: yes you are right now its working..
Thanks :)

Comment: Posted the answer. Accept the same so that it will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla cordova app, we use to invoke the plugin code inside `deviceready` event listener and in ionic framework `platform ready` is the equivalent of Cordova deviceready event.

**Invoke plugin code inside platform ready which ensures that the cordova and plugins are loaded completely.**